SSH_AUTH_SOCK security
I noticed that for SSH_AUTH_SOCK value, its folder is inaccessible by anyone else, yet the actual file itself can be read by anyone. What's the reason behind such design?
If I put a world-readable symlink in /tmp pointing to my private SSH_AUTH_SOCK file, what kind of security risk it would impose?

Symlinks don't override the permissions of the underlying file path.
eg if I do ln -s /tmp/ssh-foobarbaz/agent.12345 /tmp/mysock then to be able to access /tmp/mysock I must be able to access /tmp/ssh-foobarbaz/agent.12345, which means being able to get to /tmp/foobarbaz.  Since that directory is mode 0700 then only the owner of that directory (or root!) can access the agent.12345 and so only that person (or root!) can access /tmp/foobarbaz.
Hard links on the other hand do bypass permissions on the directory because it's an alternate path to the file.  But you need to be able to access the file in the first place in order to create the hard link, so another user couldn't do this; you'd need to be "silly" and deliberately do a bad thing.
In both cases, having the socket in a mode 0700 directory means it's secure from other users (except root).
